# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. After successfully installing the package

Tags: python, mediapipe

Mediapipe was successfully install via PyCharm, OpenCV was successfully install.
However,
I get this error:

```
from mediapipe.python._framework_bindings import resource_util
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: This type of error usually appears either when the compiled library is for the wrong architecture (e.g. 32 bit library on 64 bit host) or there is a missing underlying library, like msvcr not being up to date. I wish more information would be logged for this error.
You could try with a different version of mediapipe. Also, check the source for resource_util to see what it is importing, which might give you a hint.

Comment: I have downgraded Mediapipe to the oldest version..still now working. I will try updating the rests..

Answer (score 3):

I have eventually solved the problem by installing msvc-runtime.

```
pip install msvc-runtime
```

Answer (score 0):

when using python 3.7 it would throw that error, installing `msvc-runtime` did not fix the error but somehow downgrading to the earliest version of mediapipe **did** fix it. (mediapipe 0.8.0)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and found out it was caused by running through VScode and using Conda env. I just run it in terminal and the DLL error disappears.