# In Python creating HandTrackingProject error

Tags: python, opencv

I import opencv And mediapipe then add code to display image.

```
import cv2

import mediapipe as mp

import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while True:

    success, img = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow("image",img)

    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

It show me this error............... plz help me if any developer know this error

```
D:\pythonProject\handTracksecnond\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/pythonProject/handTracksecnond/handTrackingMin.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:/pythonProject/handTracksecnond/handTrackingMin.py", line 2, in <module>
        import mediapipe as mp
      File "D:\pythonProject\handTracksecnond\venv\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
        import mediapipe.python
      File "D:\pythonProject\handTracksecnond\venv\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
        from ._framework_bindings import resource_util
    ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _framework_bindings: The specified module could not be found.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there was an error when you installed the module `mediapipe`.
I would suggest trying to reinstall the module using

```sh
pip uninstall mediapipe
pip install mediapipe
```

Some people [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66938116/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-after-suc) the issue by doing

```sh
pip install msvc-runtime
```

I hope this was helpful

Comment: it show me this error   [ WARN:0] global C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-kuwfz3h3\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (438) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/pythonProject/handTracksecnond/handTrackingMin.py", line 12, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("image",img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-kuwfz3h3\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:404: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

Comment: thank you sir I add this code------ 
captureDevice = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW) #captureDevice = camera
and also download visual c++ it solve my issue.         thank you sir God bless you

Comment: Don't forget to mark this question as solved if your problem is fixed

Comment: thank you sir for your help . dont for get to Vot.e my quesiotion to